# How should my MongoDB schema for general content of varying format (text, image, audio, video) be structured?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to store videos, images, audio, and text posts in our database and link them users. The large content like audio and images will be stored in GridFS.

Originally I was going to store each kind in its own schema, and tie it all together with references.

For example:

```
const textSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    _createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    created: Date,
});
```

Documents for users will have a reference to image schemas for avatars and what not.

Then I was going to have a generalcontent schema that would be one long list of all collections for sorting purposes. IE:

```
const contentSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    contentType: String, //video? Image? Audio?
    content: type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: //the id of the actual content stored in other collections,
    _createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    created: Date,
});
```

But I recently read that references are bad in Mongo. Would I be better off storing all content in one schema type?

Comment: first of all - using GridFS for binary content is fine - you get the benefit of High Availability replica sets.  Trying to force binary content into a non-GridFS solution will defeat the purpose of GridFS and chunk management and you will need to roll-your-own solution if you go above the 16MB doc size limit - which seems very likely.  GridFS has a metadata field you can put your own metadata in, such as title, createdby, owner, etc.

Comment: This would result in a single schema solution.  I would recommend to created indexes on the metadata fields for performance reasons.

Comment: To recap: Binary contents (like photos or music) is fine in GridFS, BUT I should be storing the title, the creation data, the owner in the gridFS metadata rather than in a separate Mongo model that associates with the GridFS document filename?

And second, you think I should do a single schema for performance reasons?

Comment: I needed to have a reminder/primer on GridFS.  For my testing I used Java.  I rediscovered that you can only download a file if you know the filename or the ID of the file.  While custom metadata is supported it appears you must first query the metadata to get either the filename or the ID.  The ID is preferred because you might have multiple versions a file by filename and would need to evaluate the revision.

Comment: So, backing up a bit and taking a look at the bigger picture, you can use GridFS and gain the benefit of HA, or you could roll-your-own chunking strategy in the DB to have HA, or have metadata in a database collection but have the actual file on a filesystem referred to by the metadata record in the database.

Comment: If you decide to use the GridFS but need to query on metadata fields it will be a two step process for each document - first query the collection.files records using the metadata fields (to get the record ID) then call an API to fetch the chunks of the file to reconstitute the file itself.  The content type could simply be a metadata value in GridFS.